# Using existing css class in Stripe Elements for React

Tags: css, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use our existing CSS classes in my `Stripe Elements` form. According to this document https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference under section Elements options, I can pass my existing `CSS` classes but my code below didn't work.

```
const customStripeClasses = {
   base: 'app-form-default input',
};

class MyPaymentForm extends Component {

   render() {

      return(
         <div>
             <CardElement classes={customStripeClasses} />
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to get Stripe Elements form components to use the `CSS` classes we created for regular HTML elements e.g. input, textarea, etc.

Any idea how I can get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried adding your css class to `empty` property of `customStripeClasses` ?

Comment: I just tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: I reproduced your code and it's working for me, keep in mind that your css applies to the container of Stripe's input, you may add additionnal selectors in your css to apply your style properly. You can add a `box-shadow` in your class to see if it's working.

Comment: Yes, it is working but for some reason it doesn't work if I enter two class names as in `app-form-default input`. But when I combined those two into one as `my-pretty-class` and placed in `empty`, it worked.

Comment: @Dyo Thank you for your help. Your suggestion is the correct solution. If you post your response as an answer, I can accept it so that you get credit for it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from the docs you need to use [`react-stripe-elements`](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements) to use stripe with react. And `CardElement` has no prop `classes`. You can pass css classes to it with `className`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {CardElement} from 'react-stripe-elements';

class CardSection extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CardElement className="app-form-default input" />
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: @Sam This is of course only a snippet. To make it work you have to follow the instructions on [Getting Started](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements#getting-started). You will need a `StripeProvider `. Could you be a little more precise. What does not work for you? So I can improve my answer.

Comment: I've followed the getting started instructions and am able to render the CardElement. What I was saying is that `className="app-form-default input"` doesn't work. The CardElement is not using my css classes if I pass it using `className` like I would in a regular React component.

Comment: It's interesting. Just had a chat with a Stripe support guy in https://webchat.freenode.net/ He suggested the correct way is what you suggested. Let me try it again. Maybe I'm making a mistake somewhere.